# Warning when starting up the RCP Application

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

I am working on eclipse kepler rcp. I am using osgi bundles. when i startup the application I am always getting  the following message

> Enabling components of bundle com.p2pframework.main did not complete in 30000 ms
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2014-03-10 00:03:09.774 !MESSAGE
>   [SCR - WorkThread] Timeout occurred! Thread was blocked on processing
>   [QueuedJob] WorkPerformer:
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager@104e583; actionType 1

Comment: Looks like a problem with starting an OSGi service in the declarative services code. Do you have a service that takes a long time to start?

Comment: It was working fine before. But now it shows one of the bundle did not complete in 30000 ms..@greg-449

Comment: after restarting the system it works fine. Its weird..